# Particle explosion length (time) decreasing as app runs

Tags: android

EDIT: I was able to fix the issue by storing the explosions into an ArrayList, however I am not sure that this is good practice. Is it ok to leave it like that and just allow the arraylist to get bigger and bigger? The game will end way before the arraylist gets larger than 200 or so, but I just want to practice the best style.

I am currently making a very, very simple game for android (first project ever) where you have a bunch of circles that move across the screen and they "explode" when you tap them. The way I have implemented this is that once it registers that you have tapped inside of the circle's coordinates, the particles are generated at the spot you tapped and "explode" in random directions.

The problem I'm having is that the lifetime of the particles decreases as the app runs, despite the variable being a constant number. The first few taps are perfect, they last the correct amount of time. As you continue to play, the explosions get shorter and shorter until they are merely flashes. I am not sure what would cause this.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public class Explosion {

private static final String TAG = Explosion.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int STATE_ALIVE = 0;    //at least 1 particle is alive
public static final int STATE_DEAD  = 1;    //all particles are dead

private Particle[] particles;           //particles in the explosion
private int x, y;                       //the explosion's origin
private int state;                      //whether it's still active or not

public Explosion(int particleNr, int x, int y) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Explosion created at " + x + "," + y);
    this.state = STATE_ALIVE;
    this.particles = new Particle[particleNr];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
        Particle p = new Particle(x, y);
        this.particles[i] = p;
    }
}

public Particle[] getParticles() {
    return particles;
}

public void setParticles(Particle[] particles) {
    this.particles = particles;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public boolean isAlive() {
    return this.state == STATE_ALIVE;
}

public boolean isDead() {
    return this.state == STATE_DEAD;
}

public void update(Rect container) {
    if (this.state != STATE_DEAD) {
        boolean isDead = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
            if (this.particles[i].isAlive()) {
                this.particles[i].update(container);
                isDead = false;
            }
        }
        if (isDead)
            this.state = STATE_DEAD; 
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
        if (this.particles[i].isAlive()) {
            this.particles[i].draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

}

^Explosion class

```
public class Particle {

public static final int STATE_ALIVE = 0;
public static final int STATE_DEAD = 1;

public static final int DEFAULT_LIFETIME = 500000;
public static final int MAX_DIMENSION = 4;
public static final int MAX_SPEED = 3;

private int mState;
private float mWidth;
private float mHeight;
private float mX,mY;
private double mXVel, mYVel;
private int mAge;
private int mLifetime;
private int mColor;
private Paint mPaint;

public Particle(int x, int y) {
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    mState = Particle.STATE_ALIVE;
    mWidth = rndInt(1,MAX_DIMENSION);
    mHeight = mWidth;
    mLifetime = DEFAULT_LIFETIME;
    mAge = 0;
    mXVel = (rndDbl(0, MAX_SPEED * 2) - MAX_SPEED);
    mYVel = (rndDbl(0, MAX_SPEED * 2) - MAX_SPEED);

    //smoothing out the diagonal speed
    if (mXVel * mXVel + mYVel * mYVel > MAX_SPEED * MAX_SPEED) {
        mXVel *= .7;
        mYVel *= .7;
    }
    mColor = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
    mPaint = new Paint(mColor);
}

public int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public void setState(int state) {
    mState = state;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public void setWidth(float width) {
    mWidth = width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    mHeight = height;
}

public float getX() {
    return mX;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    mX = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return mY;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    mY = y;
}

public double getXVel() {
    return mXVel;
}

public void setXv(double xVel) {
    mXVel = xVel;
}

public double getYVel() {
    return mYVel;
}

public void setYv(double yVel) {
    mYVel = yVel;
}

public int getAge() {
    return mAge;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    mAge = age;
}

public int getLifetime() {
    return mLifetime;
}

public void setLifetime(int lifetime) {
    mLifetime = lifetime;
}

public int getColor() {
    return mColor;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    mColor = color;
}

private int rndInt(int min, int max) {
    return (int) (min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

private double rndDbl(double min, double max) {
    return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}

public boolean isAlive() {
    return mState  == STATE_ALIVE;
}

public boolean isDead() {
    return mState == STATE_DEAD;
}

public void update(Rect container) {
    // update with collision
    if (this.isAlive()) {
        if (mX <= container.left || mX >= container.right - mWidth) {
            mXVel *= -1;
        }
        // Bottom is 480 and top is 0 !!!
        if (mY <= container.top || mY >= container.bottom - mHeight) {
            mYVel *= -1;
        }
    }
    update();
}

public void update() {
    if (mState != STATE_DEAD) {
        mX += mXVel;
        mY += mYVel;

        //extract alpha
        int a = mColor >>> 24;
        //fade by 2
        a -= 2;
        //if transparency is reached then particle dies
        if (a <= 0) {
            mState = STATE_DEAD;
        } else {
            //set new alpha
            mColor = (mColor & 0x00ffffff) + (a << 24);
            mPaint.setAlpha(a);
            mAge++;
        }
        //particle reached end of its lifetime
        if (mAge >= mLifetime) {
            mState = STATE_DEAD;
        }
    }
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    mPaint.setColor(mColor);
    canvas.drawRect(mX, mY, mX + mWidth, mY + mHeight, mPaint);
}
```

}

Below is updatePhysics() method in my view class

```
public void updatePhysics() {
int pWidth = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bullet).getWidth();
    for (int i = 0; i < pummels.size(); i++) {
        //checks collision with left side wall
        //changes direction if it collides
        pummels.get(i).update();
if (pummels.get(i).getSpeed().getxDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_LEFT && pummels.get(i).getX() - pWidth / 2 <= 0) {
            totalHp--;
            setHP("HP: " + String.valueOf(totalHp));
            pummels.remove(i);
        }
        if (pummels.size() == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                pummels.add(j, new  Pummel(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bullet), 850, (int) (Math.random() * 200) + 80));
            }
        }
        if (explosion != null && explosion.isAlive()) {
            explosion.update(getHolder().getSurfaceFrame());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the run class and my attempt to maintain constant FPS

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

        long beginTime;
        long timeDiff;
        int sleepTime = 0;
        int framesSkipped;

        while(mRunning) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    framesSkipped = 0;
                    mGamePanel.updatePhysics();
                    mGamePanel.render(c);
                    timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                    sleepTime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                    /if (sleepTime > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    while (sleepTime <= 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                        mGamePanel.updatePhysics();
                        sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                        framesSkipped++;
                    }

                    if (framesSkipped > 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Skipped:" + framesSkipped);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I apologize, I thought I had it in there.

Comment: Updated OP with my attempt to maintain FPS. Sorry for indentations, couldn't format it correctly in the post. A lot of my code is derived/taken from tutorials I found (trying to learn the proper practices for this stuff, but had a lot of trouble finding good tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

To start diagnosing this, I would do the following. Basically, I would verify point 1 and 2 that nothing wierd is going on, then move to point 3, and if that doesn't help, then point 4 might be of some use.

1. Log out the time remaining at several key points. Updates are required, and upon creation wouldn't be a bad idea either.
2. Print out the `a` values while you are at it.
3. It could be that the game is simply updating more the fewer things that it has to deal with. Perhaps putting the frames on some sort of a timer will help to ensure that the time is constant (And is a good idea anyways).
4. There seems to be something weird with your particle creation mapping. Specifically, how do you know a particle is dead? It could be that a particle is alive, but you are overwriting it, causing some weird behavior.

Comment: For point 4. The particle is declared dead once its "age" has reached its "lifetime" and lifetime is a constant. Age is increased each time the alpha is decreased.

Also could you elaborate on your 2nd point? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Kinru: #4 was a bit of a long shot. I'm just wondering if somehow the age is being mixed up... Actually, upon further thought I doubt it even more than I did when I wrote it... Still, I'm betting that point #3 is your real culprit.

Comment: Ah sorry, I wrote the wrong number in my previous comment. I meant to ask you to elaborate on your third point >.< In my run loop, in order to create a consistent FPS, I have a counter that counts the frames skipped and updates the game so that it does not appear choppy. If there is left over time after update and draw, then it sleeps instead.

Could the problem be that I am overwriting each explosion every time there is a new one? I did not put them inside of an arraylist because I couldn't figure out a good way of removing the explosions that ended.

Comment: @Kinru: In order to detect such things, perhaps printing the time of each update() statement could help. If you see inconsistencies, then there is something wrong going on with your method of maintaining constant FPS.

Comment: Thank you, I just tested that as well and it updates correctly. I think the problem was that I was overwriting the explosions. I think I solved it by putting the explosions into an arraylist